# Беспорядок в метке [sendmessage]

Tags: обсуждение, метки, использование-метки

Недавно наткнулся на вопрос с меткой [sendmessage](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sendmessage). У него очень общее описание *"Метка, связанная с методами отправки каких-либо сообщений"*, поэтому её можно приписать к практически любой теме. Сейчас из всех (48) вопросов есть вопросы по: [winapi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winapi), [facebook-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-api), [telegram-bot](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/telegram-bot) (c [telegram](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/telegram) и [telegram-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/telegram-api)) [vkontakte-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vkontakte-api), [chrome-extension](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chrome-extension). [На enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sendmessage/info) чуть более подробное описание со ссылкой на документацию *winapi*.

Удалять эту метку, конечно же, не стоит, но, я считаю, необходимо улучшить описание, что бы не мешалась с другими темами. Оставим эту метку вместе с *winapi*? Или сделаем что-то другое?

Comment: А по-моему удалять эту метку стоит, так как она слишком размытая и объединяет под собой по сути никак не связанные вопросы, следовательно бесполезна для использования

Comment: А касательно winapi — создавать метки для каждой функции в отдельности мне кажется странным

Comment: Конечно, можно и сжечь эту метку, но я не знаю, есть ли в этом необходимость. На английском стаке уже 1000 вопросов, около половины связанны с windows / c#. Конкретно меня не нравится, что эту метку используют в других апи (для VK: `messages.send(...)`). Можно подумать и переименовать в _winapi-sendmessages_, но это выглядит избыточным... В общем, лично мне не понятно, что с этой меткой делать.

Answer (score 1):

#### **Стоит ли всё-таки удалить метку?**

Я думаю, что нет. *Нет ничего плохого в том, что есть метка, которая более общая по смыслу, чем какое-либо количество других меток*. В данном случае метка **не** слишком "расплывчатая", как иногда бывает. Заметьте, темы, связанные с этой меткой, **не случайны**: большинство из них связаны с отправлением сообщений в социальных сетях.

#### **А что стоит сделать?**

Метке нужно дать нормальное описание. Описание, которое у метки на данный момент, хорошим назвать трудно:

> Метка, связанная с методами отправки каких-либо сообщений

Поэтому его надо полностью переписать. Например, неплохим будет такой вариант:

> Используйте данную метку для вопросов, которые связаны с отправкой сообщений в социальных сетях и чатах с помощью языков программирования и различных библиотек. Если речь идёт об отправке сообщений не в социальные сети и чаты, а об отправке сообщений ещё куда-либо, то данную метку использовать не рекомендуется.

Думаю, большинство вопросов с этой меткой вполне соответствуют этому описанию. В остальных эту метку можно убрать.

#### P.S.

я поправлю описание этой метки в ближайшее время.

#### Дополнение

Уже предложил правку описания метки. Думаю, если у метки будет нормальное описание, то и добавлять метку куда попало не будут.